# How to perform !(true &true) type of operation

Tags: sql, oracle

I have a deptartment table and employee table:

Department:

```
deptId   deptName
0        dept1
1        dept2
2        dept3
3        dept4
```

Employees:

```
deptId  name    type
0       aaa     100
0       bbb     200
0       ccc     300
1       ddd     100
1       eee     300
2       fff     200
2       ggg     300
3       hhh     300
```

So each department has multiple employees. How  can I retrieve all the departments who don't have employees of both type 100 and 200

So if I run the query I should get dept 1, 2 and 3 as the only department who has employees of both types is department 0

Thank you

Answer (score 3, accepted):

One method uses `not exists`:

```
select d.*
from department d
where not exists (select 1
                  from employee e
                  where e.deptid = d.deptid and e.type = 100
                 ) or
      not exists (select 1
                  from employee e
                  where e.deptid = d.deptid and e.type = 200
                 ) ;
```

If you wanted to require that the department has at least one employee, I would probably go for aggregation:

```
select e.deptid
from employee e
group by e.deptid
having count(distinct case when e.type in (100, 200) then e.type end) < 2;
```

Comment: Hi Gordon, for the first method. It if it is OR then it will return depatment that do not have 100 OR do not have 200.  Which means all departments will be returned. Right?

Comment: @Snake . . . No.  For `deptid = 0`, each `NOT EXISTS` returns `FALSE` so that department would not be returned.

Answer (score 2):

Have a correlated sub-query that returns the number of distinct types 100 and 200 for a deptid.

```
select *
from department d
where (select count(distinct type)
       from employee e
       where type in (100, 200)
         and e.deptid = d.deptid
       group by deptid) < 2
```

Or do a `LEFT JOIN` with `GROUP BY`:

```
select d.deptId, d.deptName
from department d
left join employee e
    on e.deptid = d.deptid
group by d.deptId, d.deptName
having count(case when e.type = 100 then 1 end) = 0
    or count(case when e.type = 200 then 1 end) = 0
```